# Binomial or Poisson? Binomial makes most sense but similar p values and Poisson has no overdispersion

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

I am modelling no. days exercised in a given week and so therefore I am using a binomial GLM. Yet the model is massively overdispersed (even as quasibinomial).
When I model as poisson distributed however, the overdispersion is removed.
What's more, my p value for the most significant predictor (wake-up time) is pretty much the same (0.08) when its binomial and poisson and the effect sizes are pretty similar (although I know that GLM p values etc. are just approximations).

Is the overdispersion when binomial a sign that I should model using a poisson distribution?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please edit the question to explain the source of variation? - one person observed over different days? - different people observed on the same day? And it might help to explain what you want to do with the model - the obvious defects of a Poisson model may not be especially relevant.

Comment: Please don't ask a new Q, but edit the original!